# Change Div from 'fixed' to 'absolute' AND place Div to top of current browser window position (not top of page)

Tags: jquery, css

The problem I'm having is changing a Div from position: Fixed; to the browser's current scrolled Absolute position. By default, swapping css position: Absolute locks the Div at the top of the page...not the top of the browser window...so if you have scrolled, the div jumps to the top of the html page when you click.

I hope I'm not over-explaining what seems like a simple problem.

example here -- [jsfiddle.net/zsa9a/15/](http://jsfiddle.net/zsa9a/15/)

I've tried tons of variations on $('#FloatingDiv').css({position:'absolute/relative/static/inherit', top:'AllSortsOfDifferentStuff'});

Here's where I started...

```
$('#BtnAbsolute').click(
    function () {
    $('#FloatingDiv').css({position:'absolute'});
});
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: that's whe point of absolute and fixed. I don't understand why you are trying to switch them.

Comment: So what's your expected behavior?

Comment: I didn't want to confuse things but what I'm really doing is using a single Div to load html pages, one at a time, into it. Scenario's here...

Click link...show/unhide floatingdiv...load html into it...click Close button

scroll say 1000 pixels, click another/different link, load another page into div, click close. 

If you don't reposition the floatingdiv based on window position, and you've scrolled beyond the original viewing area, you miss it. 

Anyway, Blake's solution is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is exactly the effect you are going for. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/zsa9a/17/). It sounds to me that you need to use `scrollTop()` in order to get the current windows scrolled position.

```
$('#BtnAbsolute').click( function () {
    $('#FloatingDiv').css({
        position:'absolute',
        top: $(window).scrollTop() - 20+'px'
    });
});


$('#BtnFixed').click(function () {
    $('#FloatingDiv').css({
        position:'fixed',
        top: 0
    });  
});
```